# How can I return true when buying two mixed figures that are the same but have the components in a different order?

Tags: java

[image]
The mixed figures are composed of 4 parts, 2 of land and 2 of water, how can I make a comparator method so that it returns True in case they are figures composed of the same proportions but that are stored in a different order?

[image]
here is my uml

```
package ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.Ejercicio1;

import java.util.\*;

public class TopografiaMixta extends Topografia {
private Vector\<Topografia\> componentes;

    public TopografiaMixta(Topografia t1, Topografia t2, Topografia t3, Topografia t4) {
        this.componentes = new Vector<Topografia>(4);
        this.componentes.add(t1);
        this.componentes.add(t2);
        this.componentes.add(t3);
        this.componentes.add(t4);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public double calcularProporcion() {
        return this.componentes.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.calcularProporcion()).sum() / 2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean comparar(Topografia t1) {
        if(this.componentes.equals(t1)) {
            return true;
        };
        return false;
    }

}
```

here is my abstract class!

```java
package ar.edu.unlp.info.oo2.Ejercicio1;

public abstract class Topografia {
    public abstract double calcularProporcion();
    public abstract boolean comparar(Topografia t1);
}
```

Comment: You're talking about a comparator and returning a boolean. Could you clarify if you need an equals method that returns true if the two objects are composed with the same elements or a compareTo method that returns an integer to establish their natural order. Furthermore, you should also provide the implementation of the Topografia class to help you in defining the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

First check if t1 is instance of TopografiaMixta, if is `return this.calcularProporcion() == t1.calcularProporcion();`,
if is not `return false;`.

Or

You can make a loop and count how many proportions of water and how many of land are in each figure. Then compare if the proportions of water and land are equal in both figures.